# How to enforce cap/limit on the commission amount in Oracle Incentive Compensation?

Tags: oracle

I am stuck in a problem. I have a commission type in which I have to put a limit on the commission amount. Following are the details:

Suppose that the limit of the compensation amount is $200.

Now what I need is that if my transaction amount is greater than equal to $50 and less than equal to 200 ( 50 <= TRANSACTION_AMOUNT <= 200 ), then the commission amount should be 100% of the transaction amount i.e. if T.Amount is $150 then the commission will be $150, similarly if the T.Amount is 200, the commission amount will be $200.

However if the T.Amount is $500, the commission amount should still be $200. How can this be achieved?

Kindly advice.

Comment: `least(200, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)`

Comment: Thanks Egor, 
Yes this is also a good way to do that. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming commission for transaction amount below 50 is 0 the following formula will work

input expression: transaction_amount

rate table:

```
0-50--------0
50 - 200 ------------1
200-9999999----------200
```

outputexpression:decode(ratetableresult,1,transaction_amount,ratetableresult)

Comment: Thanks a lot Vijay,
It works fine now. Highly appreciate your help here.